# Why can't I write FileWriter outside of Try with resources?

Tags: java, file, filereader, file-handling, filewriter

So, I just wanted to create a program to copy the contents from one file(source1) to another file(source2) and convert it into lowercase... while doing so i have came up with the code as:

```
        try(FileWriter fr=new FileWriter("Source1.txt")){
            String str="UPPER CASE";
            fr.write(str);
        }


        File file=new File("Source1.txt");
        //FileReader fr=new FileReader("Source1.txt"); // (1)
        //FileWriter f2=new FileWriter("Source2.txt"); // (2)

        try(FileReader fr=new FileReader("Source1.txt");FileWriter f2=new FileWriter("Source2.txt")){ //If i remove 
//file Reader from here and uncomment (1) the code works fine but if i do so with FileWriter (Remove
//fileWriter from here and uncomment (2)) I can't copy the contents of the file (No error is shown... the code executes but Source2.txt just comes out as blank file.


            char x[]=new char[(int)file.length()];
            fr.read(x);
            String str=new String(x);
            System.out.println(str);
            String st=str.toLowerCase();
            f2.write(st);


        }
```

Nothings wrong with the code but i just wanted to know why does it work this way(please read the comment in the code)?

Comment: Your comment says "I can't copy the contents of the file". Why not? Do you get a compiler error? A run-time exception? Please post details (including any error messages or stack traces as applicable).

Comment: If you don't use try-with-resources, you need to take care of calling `close()` on the file handlers yourself. Try-with-resources is better: stick with that.

Comment: @TedHopp No error is shown... The source2.txt will just be blank ... I thought there will be no point in putting a blank output.

Comment: @khelwood I just wanted to know what does it work with fileReader being outside of try block but not fileWriter

Comment: @SomethingNice Presumably because you didn't close the filewriter and some of what you tried to write was still cached.

Comment: @SomethingNice It looks like you have not understood scopes and why try-resource-catch is used. Please look for examples, they will all clear it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the writer is out of try-with-resources, you need to take care of flushing and closing the writer using

```
f2.flush()
f2.close()
```

flush() flushes the stream. If the stream has saved any characters from the various write() methods in a buffer, it writes them immediately to their intended destination.

Try-with-resources does the same implicitly.

Comment: Usually the call to `flush()` is unnecessary. The call to `close()` will make sure the output is flushed before the underlying output stream is closed. The only reason to call `flush()` just before calling `close()` is to separately handle any exceptions that may arise when flushing the stream. Such exceptions are swallowed when `close()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use `try-with-resource` you must close the resource yourself.
This can be necessary to have any cached data written to the stream (flush), e.g.  writing to a file; also good to free system resources.

---

```
try (var resource = new Resource()) {
    // statements
}
```

is basically (ignoring error handling/exceptions) the same as:

```
var resource = new Resource();
// statements
resource.close();
```

or (a bit better)

```
var resource = new Resource();
try {
    // statements
} finally {
    resource.close();
}
```

This can get somehow complicated if error handling is added - so it is better to  use `try-with-resource` (at the very least it makes the code much easier to read/understand/maintain).

Comment: This is correc. But this will point him in the wrong direction. So I do NOT support this.

Comment: f2.flush() works too. So, The content written will stay in Buffer and will not be flushed till f2.close() is called. If i want to bypass this then i can use f2.flush() without closing(Which is not recommended).